# Is there a way to create a generic model to write a Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, arrays, json, mongodb, system.text.json

I am working on an application where users can store localizations.

The issue I am facing is that the localizations that users can store can be **Key, value** But also **Key, Object** and there is no limit to the nesting that people do in the application. For example:

This should be possible:

```
"translation": {
  "settings": "Settings",
  "presets": "Presets"
}
```

This should also be possible:

```
"translation": {
  "presets": "Presets",
  "testCategory": {"settings": "Settings"}
}
```

How can I create a generic model that accepts both scenarios?

The property that I currently use:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> Translation { get; set; }
```

This get's the data from MongoDB correctly. But once I want to write data to MongoDB I get:

> Type System.Text.Json.JsonElement is not configured as a type that is allowed to be serialized for this instance of ObjectSerializer.

Comment: How can there be no limit to nesting? Is that like a graph structure? Its weird in the context of translations. So the first solution is to disallow arbitrary nesting and to make the schema stable. If nesting is absolutely necessary, then it still can be done with stable schema (e.g. recursive structure), you will probably need a custom (de)serializer.

Comment: There is eventually a limit to nesting but you can't really know when that limit is. I will look into the recursive structure. Thankyou for the fast response!

Comment: `System.Text.Json.JsonElement` where has it come from?

Comment: ie what particular objects breaks inserting

Comment: @dododo It happens when i try to insert a nested translation. the 2nd example from above.

Comment: I don't see how JsonElement may appear there, this is something on your end